# Подскажите как сверстать эту секцию

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

[image: Секция]
Используя flexbox  я смогу их так установить, но что делать с линиями? 
Или же сделать что-то на подобии [адаптивной галереи](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=1338), а как тогда адаптивить, что с линиями делать?

Как верстать такую секцию? Подскажите. Может быть примеры есть какие.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/L8hk22cx/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  counter-reset: b-item;
}
.b-item {
  max-width: 220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.b-item:nth-of-type(even) {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.b-item:nth-of-type(even) p {
  order: 1;
}
.b-item:before,
.b-item:after {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  background: #fff;
}
.b-item:nth-of-type(odd):after,
.b-item:nth-of-type(even):before {
  counter-increment: b-item;
  content: counter(b-item)" ";
}
.b-item .fa {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #c00;
}
.b-item .fa:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #555;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
.b-item .fa:nth-of-type(1):after {
  left: 50%;
}
.b-item:nth-of-type(odd) .fa:after {
  transform: rotate(-16deg);
}
.b-item:nth-of-type(even) .fa:after {
  transform: rotate(16deg);
}
.b-item:last-of-type .fa:after {
  border: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .b {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .b-item:nth-of-type(even) {
    padding-top: 25px;
  }
  .b-item .fa:after {
    display: none;
  }
  .b-item:nth-of-type(odd):after {
    display: none;
  }
  .b-item:before {
    counter-increment: b-item;
    content: counter(b-item)" ";
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="b">
  <div class="b-item">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>text text text text text text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-item">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>text text text text text text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-item">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>text text text text text text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-item">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>text text text text text text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-item">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>text text text text text text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="b-item">
    <i class="fa fa-diamond" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>text text text text text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```